# Decomposition of a dense matrix into $m$ tridiagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, tridiagonal-matrices

Given an $n\times n$ dense matrix $\mathbf{K}$, is there any decomposition that factorizes $\mathbf{K}$ into $m$ tridiagonal matrices such that $\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{B}_1 \, \mathbf{B}_2 \, \mathbf{B}_3 \cdots \mathbf{B}_m$ where each $\mathbf{B}_i$ has the following form?

$$\mathbf{B}_i = \begin{pmatrix}
d_1 & u_1 \\
l_1 & d_2 & u_2 \\
& l_2 & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & u_{n-1} \\
& & & l_{n-1} & d_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that $m$ is not given. It could potentially be as small as $(n−1)$, as the product of $(n−1)$ tridiagonal matrices would create a fully dense matrix. However, I'm not sure that any arbitrary given $\mathbf{K}$ can be factorized with $(n−1)$ terms.

*Background & Context*

I'm an applied physicist working with topological optimization of 2D structures in wave physics.  When performing such an optimization, we are trying to map the complex amplitude of $n$ input modes onto $n$ output modes.  As such, the completed devices are performing parallel analog dense matrix multiplication. [link](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/363/6433/1333/tab-figures-data)

I would like to understand required size of the structure (in wavelengths) prior to optimization.  Numerically, I find that there is a minimum size, below which the optimizer does not find a good solution.

My thinking is that the problem can be reduced by imagining that there is a small finite width $\Delta x$ which effectively exchanges energy between neighboring forward propagating modes and that this finite width could be found.  A slab of this finite width would be equivalent to a tridiagonal matrix, mapping a set of input modes only onto their *neighboring* output modes.  In order to achieve a dense matrix, one would need $m$ such energy exchanges between neighboring modes and the final size would be $m \cdot \Delta x$.

A related but slightly less abstract application would be for use in a mesh.  Suppose that you have $n$ input cables each carrying a complex amplitude.  On a given layer, each of these cables mixes with its nearest neighbors in some way, potentially using Mach-Zender Interferometers.  A layer would again be performing the operation of multiplication by a tridiagonal matrix.  How many layers, $m$, of local mixing would be necessary to achieve an arbitrary dense matrix and how would one find the values of the individual mixers?

However, after a bit of Googling, I wasn't able to find any factorization schemes which break a dense matrix into $m$ tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: Have you tried starting with Toeplitz matrices?

Comment: Not at all what you are looking for, but this might be interesting. Every $n \times n$ matrix is the product of Toeplitz matrices as per [this paper](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/work/toeplitz.pdf).

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/gji/article/103/2/565/593088 the Lanczos iteration uses this but it doesn't explicitly make the matrix as the product of tridiagonal matrices. It is a Krylov method.